# Rails - Validate model in another controller and persist errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rest, activerecord

I have two models `User` and `Want`. A `User` `has_many:` `Want`s.

The `Want` model has a single property besides `user_id`, that's `name`.

In the `edit` action view in the `UsersController` there are two forms. One POSTs (PUT) to the `UsersController` update method to update the user, another POSTs to the `WantsController` `create` action to add a new `Want` to the user's account.

This is fine and I have it working, but...

In the `create` action of the `WantsController` I redirect back to the `edit` action of the `UsersController` to show success or `Want` validation errors.

The issue is that the edit action creates a new @want for the form and the validation errors are lost in the request.

Check out the `create` action in the `UsersController`:

```
def create
    @want = current_user.wants.build(params[:want])
    if @want.save
      flash[:success] = "WANT created!"
      redirect_to user_account_path current_user.username
    else
      #flash[:validation] = @want.errors <- I NEED THESE ERRORS FOR MY VIEW
      redirect_to user_account_path current_user.username
    end
  end
```

and the edit action of the `UsersController`:

```
def edit
  @want = @user.wants.build
  super
end
```

Because the `WantsController` redirects I lose the errors in the `@want` instance variable. I can store the errors in the `flash` (as shown in the comment) but surely this is a complete misuse of the `flash`.

So my question is, how can I persist those errors accross the action so I can render in my view the `Want` validation errors?

Also, is this considered a validation of Rails conventions? Seems a bit overkill to create a whole new page so a user can add a single want with one string property!

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just store the errors in another class variable, something like `@latest_errors = @want.errors`

Comment: The vars aren't retained over the request, that's the issue.

Comment: I meant class variables (@@latest_errors and not @latest_errors), which do not retain state over requests in development environment, but in production they do. If you want, you can change this configuration in development as well. Just change development config file (config/environments/development.rb) as follows `config.cache_classes = true`

Comment: Ah that is interesting! I'll explore that.

Comment: Woah. Please don't give or follow this advice re. `@@class` vars and `config.cache_classes`. It's terrifying. Definitely not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than redirecting, it is more common to render in this kind of situation:

```
if @want.save
  …
else
  @user = current_user
  render 'users/edit', status: 400
end
```

There are some downsides to this though:

- If the `users/edit` template changes and requires an additional instance variable, you now have to change two controller actions. You can get around this by using a [presenter object](http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/03/rails-presenter-pattern.html) that contains everything you need to render the `users/edit` view.
- If there is a lot going on on the `users/edit` page, it might be difficult for the user to spot the error they are trying to correct. If this is the case I would argue that adding a `wants/new` view that just displays the form for creating a new want would simplify matters. You can always share the form code between `wants/new` and `users/edit` using a [partial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials).

Comment: Yeah this is the solution I feared. I don't want to render because the  user will remain on localhost:3000/wants rather than the URL they came from. This is a tough problem but I'm sure there will be something I can do.

Comment: I think they *should* be on that URL. They have POSTed to it, and the POST failed because the data was invalid, so it should return a 4xx response code and explain the problem. This is normal behaviour for most Rails apps, and IMO a good interpretation of the HTTP spec.

Comment: True except that Rails validation errors are delivered as `200 OK`.

Comment: The status code after validation errors is up to the app author. I most commonly see 422 (unprocessable entity, from the WebDAV spec). I'll edit the answer to add this to the example code.